# Automatically print word document using bat file

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, batch-file, printing

Automatically print word document using bat file

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\winword.exe" "D:/new/CABSC.docx" /mFilePrintDefault /mfileexit

using this bat file I am able to print one word document automatically.

But I have more than 100 word document with different name. Is that possible to call them here to print all the word document using this bat file.

Comment: Yes. Hint: look into `forfiles`, then try things, and then come back with specific questions about specific problems you run into. As-is you've shown little to no research effort on writing your batch file, so you may get down-votes.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "winword=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\winword.exe"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
  dir /b /s "c:\path\docs\*.docx"
') do (
  "%winword%" "%%~a" /mFilePrintDefault /mfileexit
)
```

Used [`SET VARIABLE`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html), [`wildcards`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) inside [`DIR`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) inside [`FOR`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html).

Answer (score 2):

I [found](http://www.extension.uner.edu.ar/adjuntos/descargas/Imprimir.Expediente.vbs) a VBS script that prints all documents in the folder it's executed in:

```
set shApp = CreateObject("shell.application")
currentPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".") 
set shFolder = shApp.NameSpace( currentPath )
set files = shFolder.Items()
for each files in files

    if files.name <> "Imprimir.Expediente" then
        'msgbox("printing "&files.name) 
                                files.InvokeVerbEx ("Print") 

    end if
next
```

Maybe this could do it for you.